# Не могу добить код на баше

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Решил попробовать по фану сделать код на баше, которий будет затормаживать пк полностью. С ??? раза получилось застопить ПК на +- минуту, после чего сработала защита (/bin/bash: предупреждение: слишком высокий уровень командного процессора (1000); сбрасывается до 1), с таким кодом:
Файл CRASHER.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(./CRASHER2.sh)
sleep .5
```

Файл CRASHER2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(./CRASHER.sh)
sleep .5
```

но на второй раз сразу срабатывала защита. Если кто-то знает, как это сделать, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Вы не [*fork bomb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) ищете?

Comment: Определите термин *затормаживать*. Занимать процессор чем-то, или просто устроить локальную DoS атаку? Если второе, то это комментарием выша, а если первое, то есть более интеллигентные способы.

Comment: Очень благодарю, @Ainar-G . Оказывается есть более простой способ это сделать.